# Conditional criteria in powershell group measure-object?

Tags: powershell, grouping

I have data in this shape:

```
externalName,day,workingHours,hoursAndMinutes
PRJF,1,11,11:00
PRJF,2,11,11:00
PRJF,3,0,0:00
PRJF,4,0,0:00
CFAW,1,11,11:00
CFAW,2,11,11:00
CFAW,3,11,11:00
CFAW,4,11,11:00
CFAW,5,0,0:00
CFAW,6,0,0:00
```

and so far code is

```
$gdata = Import-csv $filepath\$filename | Group-Object -Property Externalname;
$test = @()
$test += foreach($rostername in $gdata) {
    $rostername.Group | Select -Unique externalName,
    @{Name = 'AllDays';Expression = {(($rostername.Group) | measure -Property day).count}},
}
$test;
```

What I can't work out is how to do a conditional count of the lines where *day* is non-zero.
The aim is to produce two lines:

```
PRJF, 4, 2, 11
CFAW, 6, 4, 11
```

i.e. Roster name, roster length, days on, average hours worked per day on.

Answer (score 1):

- You need a where-object to filter for non zero workinghours
- I'd use a `[PSCustomObject]` to generate a new table

**EDIT a bit more efficient with only one Measure-Object**

```
## Q:\Test\2018\08\06\SO_51700660.ps1
$filepath = 'Q:\Test\2018\08\06'
$filename = 'SO_S1700660.csv'

$gdata = Import-Csv (Join-Path $filepath $filename) | Group-Object -Property Externalname

$test = ForEach($Roster in $gdata) {
    $WH = ($Roster.Group.Workinghours|Where-Object {$_ -ne 0}|Measure-Object -Ave -Sum)
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        RosterName   = $Roster.Name
        RosterLength = $Roster.Count
        DaysOn       = $WH.count
        AvgHours     = $WH.Average
        TotalHours   = $WH.Sum
    }
}
$test | Format-Table
```

Sample output:

```
> .\SO_51700660.ps1

RosterName RosterLength DaysOn AvgHours TotalHours
---------- ------------ ------ -------- ----------
PRJF                  4      2       11         22
CFAW                  6      4       11         44
```